SharpPcap: OnPacketArrival Event Not Firing
Subscribing to the OnPacketArrival event does not work. Any idea what I do wrong?
using System;
using PacketDotNet;
using SharpPcap;

Console.WriteLine("Starting packet capture...");

var devices = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;

if (devices.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No network devices found.");
    return;
}

var device = devices[0];
Console.WriteLine(device.ToString());

try
{
    device.Open();

    device.OnPacketArrival += (sender, e) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var packet = Packet.ParsePacket(e.GetPacket().LinkLayerType, e.GetPacket().Data);

            if (packet is EthernetPacket ethernetPacket)
            {
                if (ethernetPacket.PayloadPacket is IPPacket ipPacket)
                {
                    if (ipPacket.DestinationAddress.ToString() == "54.220.192.176" &&
                        ipPacket.PayloadPacket is TcpPacket tcpPacket &&
                        tcpPacket.DestinationPort == 443) // HTTPS port
                    {
                        var sourceIp = ipPacket.SourceAddress;
                        var destinationIp = ipPacket.DestinationAddress;
                        var sourcePort = tcpPacket.SourcePort;
                        var destinationPort = tcpPacket.DestinationPort;

                        Console.WriteLine($"HTTPS Packet: Source IP: {sourceIp}, Source Port: {sourcePort}, Destination IP: {destinationIp}, Destination Port: {destinationPort}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error processing packet: {ex.Message}");
        }
    };

    device.StartCapture();

    Console.WriteLine("Capturing packets. Press ENTER to stop.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    device.StopCapture();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error capturing traffic: {ex.Message}");
}
finally
{
    device.Close();
}


Did you try to run it in admin mode ? I had a similar problem where I had to run visual studio in administrator mode to make my network listener works

why do you assume first device on the list is active and there is traffic ?

I tested your code out in a C# environment and found that the OnPacketArrival event does fire, but only on devices that actually receive packets.
Debug your code and find out what device in devices is definitely receiving packets, then replace your index to the corresponding device.
var device = devices[0]; // Is this device even receiving packets? Perhaps another index will work
Console.WriteLine(device.ToString());


You can check is this device that you are listening on, the one that is bound to your external IP address or does that device 0 has any addresses.
There is "Addresses" list property for that purpose.
